# PCA: Why can’t we say loadings are the coefficients used to back predict the components by the variables?

Tags: pca, eigenvalues

In [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35653/9162) @ttnphns writes

> Both eigenvectors and loadings are similar in respect that they serve
> regressional coefficients in predicting the variables by the
> components (not vice versa!)

, and in a footnote adds that

> Since eigenvector matrix in PCA is orthonormal and its inverse is its
> transpose, we may say that those same eigenvectors are also the
> coefficients to back predict the components by the variables. It is
> not so for loadings, though.

I understand the distinction between eigenvectors and loadings, as explained in many posts here. But why is it that we can say

$Component_1 = Eigenvector_{11} \times x_1 + Eigenvector_{21} \times x_2 + ...$

but not

$Component_1 = Loading_{11} \times x_1 + Loading_{21} \times x_2 + ...$

And why is it that the problem doesn’t occur when predicting variables by components?

Comment: Either you misunderstood the citations or understood them away from the context. Clearly, since loading is just an eginvector value scaled by a constant factor, you _may_ use loadings in place of eigenvectors as coefficients to compute principal component scores. In your two equations, Component_1 will be collinear with the other Component_1, but the second one will have variance $L_1^2$ while the first one will have variance $L_1$, the 1st eigenvalue. It is unusual to request a PC variance other than equal to its eigenvalue (raw PC) or to 1 (standardized PC).